# Streaming media from Mac to VLC for Android

Tags: macos, smb, android, vlc

I have few media files in my Mac which I want to stream on my Android phone. I have enabled File Sharing and enabled both smb and afp protocol. When I check in VLC for Android app, I can see my Mac's name there. However when I try to connect it, it shows me a login prompt asking me to enter username and password.

I tried my Mac's only username and password, but it didn't do anything. The username have spaces in it, so I tried some combinations (such as all lowercase, no spaces etc.), to no avail.
For eg. If my username on my mac is `Abc Xyz`, I tried `Abc Xyz`, `Abc%20Xyz`, `abcxyz`, `AbcXyz` etc. But it showed me empty directories.

So is there any way I can make that login prompt work? I even tried with giving Everyone access to the shared folders, but it still didn't work. By not working, I mean, the VLC displayed error `The directory is empty` or a login prompt again.

PS: I am on macOS Sierra (10.12.6) and the user have admin access.

Answer (score 9):

You can just enable guests to access shared folders. Go to Users and Groups and give access to Guests to Shared folders/Sharing.

Comment: thank you, enabling guest user and allowing access for guest to shared folders works

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

On most *nix systems Android included to login with a a user name which has a space you'd *escape* the space with a `\`, ie. `John\ Doe` The `\` will allow the OS / shell to know that a special character, ie. a *space* <kbd>␣</kbd> or another **special character** will be next, thus the escaping with a `\`.

---

So I was curious about how this could be done this afternoon as well, so I spent about an hour to get things setup, and I now have a working solution.

First off, my situation is a little different from yours, but essential the same.  Instead of having an Android phone, the wifey  has an Amazon Fire TV Stick.  I have some vidoes on my MBP that I'd like to watch on our TV with the Fire Stick.  The Fire Stick uses Android OS as well, and also supports VLC with no side loading BS .

I proceed to download and install VLC on the fire stick, and it appears to run fine.   There is a pretty accessible menu for accessing local network shares.

Now, comes the fun part of setting up the *Network Share*, ie. my MBP *MacBook Pro*.

> I have all my local videos files stored in `$HOME/Movies` on my macOS box, so I could make that folder accessible by setting it up as a share using *SMB* or *AFP* which is "kind of" what I did but not really.

**TL;DR**

- Create a regular user on the system and give it read access to your `$HOME/Movies` directory.

### Expanded procedure

1. Create a new user on macOS, I chose the username `media`.

   a. From `Apple Menu` select `System Preferences...`

   b. From the `System Preferences` dialog select `Users & Groups`

   c. Click the ➕ within `Users & Groups`, and create a *Standard* User.

Create a new user.
[image]

2. Create a new group within the same `Users & Groups` dialog, I chose to name the newly created group `media` as well.

Create a new group
[image]

3. Add the user which the video's belongs to, ie. in my case that would be `capin`.  And also add the `media` user to the newly created group as well.

Adding Users to a Group
[image]

4. Next turn on `File Sharing` from `System Preferences` within the `Sharing` button.

Enabling File Sharing
[image]

5. Set the `Shared Folders` and `Users` within `Sharing` `System Preferences` with the users and permissions you want for your shared folder, and remove any unused shares if so desired.

Setting Permissions for the Share
[image]

6. SMB settings

[image]

> A couple of notes, I was unable to get `AFP` to work properly, but I did have luck  getting `SMB` working.  And, another thing you'll have to input the `username` & `password` for the *media* account you setup.

**IMHO** I can't help but think creating a separate user to access media shares is a much better solution that using your daily driver  account for obvious security reasons.

cheers 
Chris

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I have tried this, but everytime I enter the password, it goes back to the list of network screen. If I enter wrong password it asks me again. I have even kept the username media with a simple password.

Comment: @noob it was rather late in the evening when I wrote that answer yesterday  but glossing over what I wrote yesterday I think I forgot one important step to getting this working.

You'll need to properly set the permissions of your `media` folder / directory.

Can you open the `Terminal.app` and do a `ls -lah` of the directory which contains your media. ie. for me it would like `ls -lah /Users/capin/Movies` and then post the output somewhere, preferably at gist.github.com or ghostbin.com

Comment: This is the best answer