# Setting up file sharing with Mac for VLC streaming

Tags: macos, imac, smb, vlc

I am trying to set up streaming from my Mac running on Ventura on the VLC app on a Google TV stick. I followed the instructions to set up smb file sharing from here from the user iPatch: [Streaming media from Mac to VLC for Android](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315050/streaming-media-from-mac-to-vlc-for-android/317474#317474)

I can access the folders and see the files using the limited access profile that was created but whenever I try to open a file, I get asked for authentication again and the same user/password that managed to access the folders does not work anymore. However, it works only when I enter the user/password of my admin profile. This does not seem ideal from a security perspective. Is there anything I missed to get it working on the limited access profile?